# Add custom status code to all responses in ASP.NET MVC web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using an ASP.NET web API and I want to send proper status code along with the response. Currently, it always returns a status of `200 OK`.

I would like to send different response statuses like

- on POST 201 Record Created
- on PUT 205 Record Modified
- on PUT 412 Validation Failed
- on DELETE 204 Record Deleted etc.

These are quite standard status codes I found and all actions in web API accepts these request types.

I am currently struggling to find a clear example of how, in one place (most probably via action filter or HTTP module) I can add that status code.

Comment: check this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results

Comment: Can i do that in centralized place without touching my already developed action methods. How to infer request type (GET,PUT,POST) and the response in one place and send status code accordingly.

Comment: you have to create delegating handlers for that http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers

Comment: @FrebinFrancis the suggestion of message handlers is really good. I didn't use them before. But I guess for this case it will be hard, because it is hard to determine what happened inside to know the right status to return (like was the record created or not!). I believe the right place to this is the place where your business is in the action method

Comment: @ A Khudairy yeh i just recommended him the common way to edit a response, i think you are right that he can do this from his business logic for now to make it more simple.

Comment: @FrebinFrancis yes I looked to your suggestion and felt the same way that I may not able to do it there.

Comment: @AKhudairy can we achieve this in onactionexecuted filter. I am looking to place it in central position because lots of API's are developed already.

Comment: Or some kind of message passing from actions to filter after executing results with minimal changes.

Comment: Sorry nothing on my mind. I guess you gotta debug the request and response in different cases (like success or failure) and see if there are certain values you can depend on. you can also pass things in Request.Items from the controller ... but I guess that would be the same as writing the result in each api!

Comment: @AKhudairy yes looks like a only option.. I will give it a try. Thanks